# Perl Match anything inside brackets placing each instance into groups

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to grab anything from inside Brackets (making sure to match only the first closing bracket `]`)

I am using

```
$text=~ /\[(\w+)]/gmi
```

to find all 7 matches in this file.

```
Testing Testing Testing
[Test]
[Test][TestTest][PPPP]
[Test] [TestTest] [PPPP]
Test]
```

It only grabs the first instance of `Test` in each line even when multiline matching is set `/m`.
I am trying to return each string that is inside brackets and nothing else (so for example not picking up `Test]`).

I tried this RegEx expression inside a regex web parser, [Regex Web Parser](https://regex101.com/r/cL1pT8/2). Which says that it should return all 7 matches.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Enum;
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Word';
use Win32::OLE; $Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;  

my (@req_array,$document,$paragraphs,$paragraph,$enumerate,$style,$text,$word,$oldfile);

    eval {$word = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application')}; 
    die "Word not installed" if $@; 

    unless (defined $word) { $word = Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application', 

    sub {$_[0]->Quit;}) or die "Oops, cannot start Word"; } 
    $word->Activate; 
    $word->{visible} = 1;

    #$oldfile =~ m!^(.+?)/([^/]+)$!;
    #my $dir = $1 . '/';
    #my $name = $2;
    #$word->ChangeFileOpenDirectory($dir);

    my $doc = $word->Documents->Open('C:\Users\n\Desktop\test.doc');

    print $ARGV[0] . "\n";

    $paragraphs = $doc->Paragraphs();

    $enumerate = new Win32::OLE::Enum($paragraphs);
    while(defined($paragraph = $enumerate->Next()))
    {
        $style = $paragraph->{Style}->{NameLocal};
        $text = $paragraph->{Range}->{Text};
        if($text=~ /\[(\w+)]/gmi)
        {
        print $1 . "\n";
        }

    }
```

Comment: `my @m = $text =~ /\[ (\w+) \]/xg;`

Comment: @ION: If the problem is solved for you, please do not just adjust the subject but mark the most relevant answer as accepted. If you needed significant effort on your own post another answer showing how you successfully solved the problem and accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you capture part of a regex, and do so with the 'g' flag - as you're doing - the result is an array, not a string.

Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @matches;
while ( <DATA> ) {
   push ( @matches, m,\[(\w+)\],g );
}

print join ("\n", @matches );


__DATA__
Testing Testing Testing
[Test]
[Test][TestTest][PPPP]
[Test] [TestTest] [PPPP]
Test]
```

Regarding multi-line strings in comments - this code works, and *should* work ok with your code. `$1` is defined each time your run the pattern match, and is the first capture group. You can access others with `$2` etc.

But this style of matching I think falls down when you're working on an arbitrary number of possible matches, which is where an array would be apt.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $multi_line_str = q{Testing Testing Testing
[Test]
[Test][TestTest][PPPP]
[Test] [TestTest] [PPPP]
Test]};

print join ("\n", $multi_line_str =~ m,\[(\w+)\],gmi  );
```

Comment: Great thanks for the answer, so when your stating /g why isn't it possible to print out all results using the $1 operator (guessing it's cause it only bothers to find the first instance of something)? Why does this only print the first instance of each newline even when /m is defined (multiline). What I expected is only receive the first Instance in the whole string instead of getting one for each line, seems to not make sense anyone know why this happens ?

Comment: `$1` is the 'first capture group'. `$2` the second. And so forth. It works for `g` matches, but it doesn't really work for an arbitrary number of matches.

Comment: Not sure what's up with the multiline? Should work (See edit). Are you perhaps getting one per _paragraph_ because that's what you're selecting?

Comment: Yes was defined as paragraphs even though they were technically just on the next line. Yea no idea why multiline isn't working but hey it works this way so I'm happy even though multiline would of been alot more useful.